# how to use purchased domain name in blogger

Tags: blogger

I tried to change the domain name of my blog. I buy a new domaine name from ovh. 
when I tried to edit the address of my blog in blogger interface, error 14 was displayed.
[image]

I have continued in order to reach others steps I copied the 2 CNAME in my ovh account. and in order to prove that the domaine name is mine I copied a recording TXT in the same table in my ovh account.
[image]

My problem is that google didn't validate my domaine.
[image]
any help please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some errors in your Zone file records, Click on the below link to check the errors:

http://www.intodns.com/footnewsarabia.com

You should try downloading the "DNS settings file" and import it through your DNS Zone file manager section/page

Also, refer https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6069231

If the above solutions does not help then provide the complete DNS setting screen shot to investigate further!!